# Does Entity Framework support ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly in SQLClient connection string

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2012

Does Entity Framework support [ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205662.aspx) in SQLClient connection string? It is in reference to [Read-Only access on an Availability Replica](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510184.aspx) feature of [AlwaysOn Availability Groups (SQL Server 2012)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510230.aspx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way I've found so far would involve creating the context using the connection string directly, instead of using a connection string name. This way you could append the `ApplicationIntent`.

```
string connectionString = string.Format("{0}; ApplicationIntent=READONLY", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppContext"].ConnectionString);

using (AppContext context = new AppContext(connectionString))
{
    var q = from row in context.table
            select row.id;
}
```

Comment: As a note here, I've had great success doing a similar approach to this but with a static "Factory" class that takes as a parameter a bool on whether write access was needed, and if false, returns an instance of the Context that has the ApplicationIntent included.  This makes for much cleaner code (not building connection strings in every class), and still achieves the goal.  Something like Factory.GetDataContext(bool needsWrite=false)