# Entity Framework and ApplicationIntent=READONLY

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, high-availability

I am using Entity Framework v6.4.4 database first in an ASP.NET Framework v4.6.2 application. This is my connection string entry in web.config:

```
<add name="MyApplicationEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyApplication.csdl|res://*/Models.MyApplication.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyApplication.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=*****;MultiSubnetFailover=True;initial catalog=****;persist security info=True;ApplicationIntent=READONLY;user id=****;password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

If ApplicationIntent=READONLY is in the connection string then I get an exception when I try to access the database:

```
The underlying provider failed on Open --> The wait operation timed out.
```

otherwise everything is fine.

I have seen this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21241299/1471850 - but this doesn't help. Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Comment: If you connect directly to the readable secondary do you get the same error?

Comment: I've experimented some more.
In the connection string, if I specify the secondary as the data source and ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly then the app works (but it can't write to the DB as expected)
If I specify the listener in the connection string and ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly I get "The underlying provider failed on Open".
If I connect to the secondary using SSMS then I can read data with ApplicationIntent=READONLY
If I connect to the listener using SSMS with ApplicationIntent=READONLY then I can read and write, and the DBA has verified that the reads are being routed correctly.